# Finding maximum value in a dictionary containing mixed items in Python

Tags: python, max

I have a dictionary with either a integer or a tuple of integers as value. How do I find the maximum integer present in dicts' values?

Example:

```
x1 = {0:2, 2:1, 3:(1, 2), 20:3}
```

should return 3
and

```
x2 = {0:2, 2:1, 3:(1, 5), 20:3}
```

should return 5

Comment: Should the `max` for your first example be `4`, because `4` is one of the keys?

Comment: For x1, should it return 3 or 4?

Comment: Yes, it should return 3. Otherwise the answer would be max(x1.keys())

Comment: I'm probably being obtuse, but I don't understand why the the max is 3 for `x1`.  Is that they key whose value is the maximum?  Or is that the largest value?  If it's the largest value, does that mean that the tuples of ints should be summed and considered as one value?  *Edit:* But if that's the case, then the max for `x2` would be 6, not five, right?

Comment: @Theodor: you need to clarify how you're getting `3` for the `x1`. Is it a sum of values? is it a non-null value key?

Comment: @Theodor: I first took my upvote off, now I'm considering down-voting. :|

Comment: @silentghost: if we're talking about a max function, how is 3 a valid answer for x1 and 4 not be?  Either the keys count toward the maximum, or they do not.

Comment: @babbitt: only counting true values?

Comment: @silentghost: thought about that, possibly.  Needs clarification from the OP.

Comment: Needs clarification or (more likely) fixing. Specifically: should the result be the maximum of the flattened values (as the x2 example) or the keys (as the x1 example -- which is probably wrong)?

Comment: @Andrew: well it's not just the keys, as we seem to have established.

Comment: It's a trick question.  *OR* it's probably a trick question.  In which case, I say "NI"

Comment: Im sorry. I changed the examples above. My bad.

Comment: @Theo, now you're confusing everyone by using wrong terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
max(max(v) if isinstance(v, collections.Iterable) else v for v in d.itervalues())
```

Needs at least Python 2.6 due to `collections.Iterable` ABC.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @NUll: yeah, I'm sorry. I actually don't know what OP wants. But I think this the solution anyway :)

Comment: @Theodor I am confused. This ignores the dict's keys completely; are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @Theodor: this gives 2 for your first example; you specified 3.

Comment: @Theodor: Either this answer is incorrect or your examples are incorrect. This gives 2 as the max for `x1`, not 3.

Comment: Im sorry. I changed the examples above. My bad. Now, this solution returns the correct values. Again, Sorry.

Comment: I guess, the expected solution presented for the first example is a typo.  3 doesn't make sense at all, because the maximum with keys included would be 4.  In either case, I've updated my answer with an example which includes the keys.

Comment: @lunaryorn: it open another can of worms. OP updated his question, it was indeed a typo and your answer is correct. No need to spoil it with some fantasies.

Comment: Oh, now I see your point. No, I dont wish to search the keys, thanks for including that though.

Comment: @SilentGhost:  Keep cool ... I simply didn't notice his update while I was still updating mine.  Thanks for reverting my answer to the correct one, but there is no need to polish your ego with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
max(max(k,max(v) if isinstance(v,collections.Iterable) else v) for k,v in x1.items())
```

The other one-liner does not take account of the keys.

This is icky because it is not the designed use of a dictionary: the keys are meant to be keys, not themselves stores of data. I think you should reconsider your data structure.

EDIT: The above was nonsense. Thanks to @SilentGhost for pointing it out.

Comment: @SilentGhost: so it does. Silly OP.

Comment: you don't need to do `max(x1.keys())`, you could just do `max(x1)`. but beyond you code just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Silent I think that was for clarification purposes. +1 to the answer for mentioning this is not how dicts are meant to be used

Comment: @Null: what it has to with clarification? those 3 lines make no sense, would raise `TypeError` on the second line even if correct syntax was used for `max_values`!

Comment: @SilentGhost: I missed a `max`; hopefully they now make sense. The `keys()` was indeed for clarification.

Comment: @katrie: no, you didn't miss `max`. doing `tuple(3)` raises `TypeError` in Python, because `3` is not an iterable! And again, you're not iterating over values with `for v in x1`, you're iterating over keys!

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of one liner not needing 2.6:

```
x1 = {0:2, 2:1, 3:(1, 2), 20:3}
x2 = {0:2, 2:1, 3:(1, 5), 20:3}
print max(max(values) if hasattr(values,'__iter__') else values for values in x1.values()) 
print max(max(values) if hasattr(values,'__iter__') else values for values in x2.values())
```

Output:

```
3
5
```

**HOWEVER** I strongly suggest to go to origin of these values and change the storing of integers to **singleton tuples**.Then you can use cleaner code:

```
x1 = {0:(2,), 2:(1,), 3:(1, 2), 20:(3,)}
x2 = {0:(2,), 2:(1,), 3:(1, 5), 20:(3,)}
for x in (x1,x2):
    print max(max(values) for values in x.values())
```

Comment: Good idea. Hey your allmost at 1000 rep. Congratulations =)

Comment: And it fits that I have just founded company called Ysisoft (Ninesoft) 9.9.2010 9 o'clock and rep is  in 990's :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this aproach:

- create a set for storing integers
- loop through the values of the dictionary

  - add integer values to set
  - add each integer value of tuple values to set
- find max of set

Something like this:

```
def maxofdict(x):
   s = set()
   for v in x.values():
      if hasattr(v, '__len__'):
         s.update(v)
      else:
         s.add(v)
   return max(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a generic `flatten()` function.  The Python standard library oddly enough doesn't provide one -- not even in `itertools` -- but googling around should get you an implementation.  If you don't mind being potentially backwards incompatible, you can `import` a "private" implementation from `tkinter`:

```
from _tkinter import _flatten as flatten

def mixed_max(d):
    return max(flatten(d.items()))

mixed_max({0: 2, 2: 1, 3: (1,2), 4: 0}) # => 4
mixed_max({0: 2, 2: 1, 3: (1,5), 4: 0}) # => 5
```

Comment: -1 for recommending usage of implementation details.  `_tkinter` is not a part of the public API, and can theoretically change at any time.

Comment: @lunaryorn Um, yeah, I specifically say that.  The implementation of the `flatten()` the poster wants is irrelevant, so grabbing one near at hand simplifies the example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the correct result for x1 = 4;

```
def maxOfMixedDict(x):
    max = 0
    for key, value in x.items():
        if(key > max):
            max = key
        try:
            for v2 in value:
                if(v2 > max):
                    max = v2
        except TypeError, e:
            pass

    return max
```